# DB design decisions

Tags: database

I am trying to make some decisions regarding a database schema (logical model).

It is a monitoring system that is split into:
Site -> Unit -> Sensors

A Site is the physical building, the Unit is the thing being monitored usually a Freezer / Chiller of some description.

Each Unit can have 1 or more Sensors.  1 Sensor may be Temperature, another may be Humidity, etc.

Each Sensor is connected to a Slave.  A Slave is a piece of equipment that is installed inside the Unit and can have Sensors attached to it.  The Slave is what talks to the system to transmit the Sensor data.

A Slave is currently limited to 2 Sensors, so more than one Slave can be fitted to a Unit if neccessary.

An Alarm is raised on the system in the following conditions:

- Sensor too warm
- Sensor too cold
- Sensor fault
- Slave not communicating

An Alarm can be Acknowledged and Actioned by a User ONCE.

I've come up with 2 models for this so far (see attached). 
I've used mostly Natural keys for the moment (some of them fairly lengthy compound keys); I find it helps with the initial logical model.  Whether they'll stay that way I don't know - I'd rather not turn this into a debate about natural or surrogate keys..!  This is more about the actual relationships.

[Model 1](http://alienmuppet.com/~marks/Work/SensorReadingLayout_V1.png)

A Slave can exist on the system here, either installed or not installed.

When it is installed, it is related to a Unit.

One of the issues I have here is that the model allows a Sensor from one Unit to be related to a Slave installed in another Unit.  To fix this I could make the Primary Key of SlaveInstalled (SlaveId, SiteCode, UnitNo) however this means that there is a subset of the Primary Key that is also unique, which breaks a rule in many people's book.

Another way I could solve this is by also relating the Sensor directly to the Slave itself, so the SlaveId specified in the Sensor relation *must* also be related to the same Unit.

Another issue I have here is that an Alarm has no other candidate key other than the surrogate key AlarmId.  Now, I don't mind surrogate keys but in all my experience and research the best DB designers always seem to state that a surrogate key should always be an *additional* key, otherwise the relationship has no meaning.  On the other hand, maybe AlarmId is not a surrogate and is the natural serial number of the Alarm..

[Model 2](http://alienmuppet.com/~marks/Work/SensorReadingLayout_V2.png)

In this Model I introduce the concept of a UnitDevice that can either be a Slave or a Sensor.

I have also changed how the Slave is identified once installed in the Unit, so the Unit itself is part of the Primary Key which eliminates the possibility of relating a Sensor to a Slave not installed in the Unit.

I'd be interested to know from DBAs is which model seems more correct?  And is there anything I've overlooked?

Although I appreciate all responses, I'm less interested in responses that say things like "Stick an ID in every table and relate it that way" - I like data integrity as well as structural integrity, and I don't think arbitrarily sticking an ID in every table is good practise.

Thanks!

EDIT: SiteCode is CHAR(8), AreaCode is CHAR(3).

Comment: Your primary keys seem to be too wide. I haven't fully grasped the domain yet but often you seem to include columns that are not required to achieve a unique value.; You can (and should) enforce uniqueness by adding unique indexes. You don't need to misuse a PK for enforcing something. The PK should be the "natural" key.

Comment: Having looked at it again, I may have missed off a couple of points.  For instance, a Unit's "Name" is unique but only within a given Area.  Unfortunately I forgot to put "Area" onto the Model.  I'll add it now, and also add where I am using a unique index.

Comment: I have updated the models a little.

Comment: I want to understand one thing: Is this a conceptual learning exercise or do you want the most pragmatic model possible? (Both would be acceptable.)

Comment: Both :-)  I'm trying to remain as faithful to old-school DB design as possible.  I don't have to worry about using any frameworks with it.  There was an old pro I used to talk to a lot about DB design and he always helped me a lot, and I liked his methodologies (he only used Surrogates where appropriate for instance and only as an additional index, and since adopting his approaches my work life has become much much easier, but I still get stuck sometimes) - unfortunately I am no longer in contact with him.